# Vertical spacing inside \equation

Tags: spacing, equations, fractions, vertical

I am writing my master's thesis and noticed that the spacing when using fractions is very small. T

```
\begin{equation} \label{ASF}    
f_{ij}^{t}=\dfrac{\sum_{d=1}^{365}(Unique\; daily-user\; searches\; for\; 
i\; and\; j)_d}{\sum_{d=1}^{365}(Unique\; daily-user\; searches\; for\; i\; 
and\; any\; firm\; j \neq i)_d}
\end{equation}
```

Can someone help? I am using the `equation` environment for to labeling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to make the necessary changes to your code because it is has not been inserted. I have added only `\displaystyle` which makes the fraction more readable for a best increase linespacing.

It is very important to know a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3300/minimum-working-example-mwe) and compilable code. At last I have used fittingly `\text` in `math-mode` as you can see, which provides better readability during reading.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation} \label{ASF}    
f_{ij}^{t}=\frac{\displaystyle \sum_{d=1}^{365} (\text{Unique daily-user searches for } i \text{ and } j)_d}{\displaystyle \sum_{d=1}^{365}(\text{Unique daily-user searches for } i \text{ and any firm } j \neq i)_d}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```